# CORS issue when calling a localhost API hosted on one port from another port

Tags: javascript, html, cors, localhost

I have a localhost Rest API POST query hosted using Docker at port 8501: http://localhost:8501/v1/models/model:predict. I have an HTML file which runs with a JavaScript script and it is hosted at http://127.0.0.1:8887/ using WebServer for Chrome. I am able to call global Rest API POST queries from my HTML-JS files and my local Rest API works fine from POSTMAN. But I am unable to call my API from my HTML-JS files.

Below is my JS file:

```
function foo() {        
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");

    var raw = JSON.stringify({"instances":[[0]]});

    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: raw,
        redirect: 'follow'
    };

    fetch("http://localhost:8501/v1/models/model:predict", requestOptions)
        .then(response => console.log(response.text()))
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));

}
```

I get the below error:

> Access to fetch at
>   'http://localhost:8501/v1/models/model:predict' from origin
>   'http://127.0.0.1:8887' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: CORS headers need to be sent by the REST API. I suggest using your web developer tools, network & console tabs to view the headers and change the configurations.  I can't remember exactly when but the wildcard doesn't always work, you may need to explicitly set localhost and 127.0.0.1 as allowed. Take note of the OPTIONS request, that is how JS requests the CORS headers.

Comment: i'm not sure about 'WebServer for chrome' but if you wish to get the same result you can use webpack-dev-server, witch include a 'proxy' option to config if you wish to use a server to call without the 'CROS' error.
i'm sure that with a little digging you would be able to find the same solution for WebServer for chrome. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have understood CORS slightly "backwards" -- the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` headers are specified on HTTP *responses*, not *requests*. This obviously implies that it's the HTTP server that sets them, not the client.

It would make for a terrible cross site security model if a script of arbitrary origin could effectively dictate to the HTTP server what kind of requests and from which origins the latter must accept.

It's the HTTP service that ultimately controls access by specifying appropriate headers in the responses it serves, and the user agent validates the cross origin request where it refuses to proceed if the server didn't indicate it allows requests from the different origin the script was served from -- the response will be discarded and an error will be thrown.

In short, you need to add the headers to the responses your REST service at `localhost:8501` generates, instead of specifying them for requests your client side script creates where they don't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

Your **server** is missing header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in response, as it is responsible what to allow or not. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS